# can not match the String get from properties file in Java

Tags: java, properties

I have a line in file `config.properties`

`clean=true`

and use following code to get this property

```
private static String clean;
Properties prop = new Properties();
try {
    prop.load(new FileInputStream("config.properties"));
    clean = prop.getProperty("clean");
}
```

I use `System.out.println(">"+clean+"<")` to see the output and get `">true<"`, which indicates there is no blank, no `\n`

However, when I use

```
if (clean == "true") {          
    // program does not go here
}
else {
    // program goes here
}
```

what is the possible reason?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

`==` checks if both objects point to the same memory location whereas `.equals()` evaluates to the comparison of values in the objects.

```
if (clean.equals("true")) {          
    // program does not go here
}
else {
    // program goes here
}
```

Comment: Try not answering again something that gets asked 10 times per day or so.

Comment: @GhostCat thanks, will keep that in mind from now .

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks, I have never thought of that. Perhaps I used cpp for so long...

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is you are using equality operator which doesn't compare literal instead references. So you have to use `equals` method to do literal check

```
if ("true".equals(check)) {          
    // Now Program will go here
}
else {
 // and now here
}
```

Comment: The other problem here is that this is an obvious duplicate.